Unbound by default?
I have been developing scripts for use in Google Sheets and now I am unable to create a script that is bound to a container/spreadsheet. Whether it's a freshly created spreadsheet or one that already has a script within the sheet, the save icon will only let me save the script to my drive which is also hindering my ability to access/make use of the the SpreadsheetApp service which is crucial to all of the scripts I am writing for my job.
The last script I was able to successfully was created to archive data onto another sheet as follows:
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Actions');
  menu.addItem('Clone - Archive Selected Rows', 'archiveSelectedRowsClone')
      .addItem('Veg - Archive Selected Rows', 'archiveSelectedRowsVeg')
      .addItem('Flower - Archive Selected Rows', 'archiveSelectedRowsFlower')
      .addItem('Mom - Archive Selected Rows', 'archiveSelectedRowsMom')
      .addToUi();
}

function archiveSelectedRowsClone() {
  archiveSelectedRows('Clone', 'Clone Archive');
}

function archiveSelectedRowsVeg() {
  archiveSelectedRows('Veg','Veg Archive');
}

function archiveSelectedRowsFlower() {
  archiveSelectedRows('Flower', 'Flower Archive');
}

function archiveSelectedRowsMom() {
  archiveSelectedRows('Mom Room/Z10', 'Mom Archive')
}

function archiveSelectedRows(sourceSheetName, destinationSheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName); 1 

  // Get the selected range
  var selectedRange = sourceSheet.getActiveRange();

  // Get the last row of the destination sheet
  var lastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();

  // Copy the formatting to the destination sheet
  selectedRange.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: false});

  // Copy the values to the destination sheet, using display values and batch setting
  var targetRange = destinationSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, selectedRange.getNumRows(), selectedRange.getNumColumns());
  var values = selectedRange.getDisplayValues();
  targetRange.setValues(values);


I don't understand what you mean by save the script to my drive.

To add a container-bound script project, choose Extensions > Apps Script in the spreadsheet, and paste the code there. Alternatively, use the Apps Script API to add your code to a script project.

About the save icon will only let me save the script to my drive. It can actually save both the script and the spreadsheet to your Drive. Just find the name of the spreadsheet in your drive then go to Extensions > Apps Script

I mean that regardless of how I access the Apps Script, including selecting Apps Script through the Extensions dropdown menu, I am being prompted to save the script directly to my local drive with no way to specify that the script is intended to be saved to it's container sheet. In other words, I am unable to create a bound script only unbound scripts. For what I am aiming to accomplish, I would need the ability to create a bound script.

Could you add a gif or screenshot to demonstrate the issue?

To create a bound script, you first have to open the file, document, form, presentation or spreadsheet that will contain the bound Apps Script project.
On Google Docs, Google Sheets and Google Slides, click Extensions, then Apps Script. If the file hasn't already a bound project, this will create a new bound project and open it. If the file already has a bound project, this will open the bound project.
To create another bound project in the same file, duplicate one of the existing bound projects.
You might use Google Apps Script API or CLASP for the above, too.
If you see "Save to Drive" next to the Apps Script project title or "Save project to Drive" when hovering over the Save button, don't worry. A bound project will still be contained by the file used to create it.
On the other hand, if you use https://script.google.com/create, this will create a stand-alone Apps Script project. The same if you go to https://script.google.com or https://drive.google.com and create a new Apps Script project from there.
